# Message: Array to string conversion, eror Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to display an result from the database to the view but I keep getting this error:

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: database/DB_query_builder.php

Line Number: 683

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\konsultasi\application\models\m_data.php
Line: 32
Function: where

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\konsultasi\application\controllers\Page.php
Line: 131
Function: lihat_data

**this my model (m_data)**

```
function lihat_data($id)
{
    $param = array('id' => $id);
    $this->db->select('tiket.subjek,siswa.nama,tiket_isi.created,tiket_isi.isi');
    $this->db->from('tiket');
    $this->db->join('siswa', 'tiket.dari=siswa.nis');
    $this->db->join('tiket_isi', 'tiket.id=tiket_isi.tiket_id');
    $this->db->where('siswa.nis', $param);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
}
```

**and this my controller**

```
function lihat($idx)
{
    $id     = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $where = array('id' => $idx);
    $data['row']   = $this->db->get_where('tiket', array('id' => $id))->row_array();
    $data['user'] = $this->m_data->lihat_data($where, 'tiket')->result();
       
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('konsul/lihat', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

**and view code**

```
<div class="card-header py-3">
            <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">
                <?= $row['subjek']; ?>
            </h6>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <?php foreach ($user as $u) { ?>
                <div class="col-lg mb-4">
                    <div class="card bg-primary text-white shadow">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <p><?= $u->nama ?></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <p><?= $u->created ?></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-white-80 small mt-2"><?= $u->isi ?></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: The Error message indicates that you have an issue with your WHERE statement.So you should head on over to the CI 3 User Guide and see where you are going wrong - https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data

Answer (score 1):

You can not add an array like that to where statement, this is wrong

```
$param = array('id' => $id);
$this->db->where('siswa.nis', $param);
```

it should be like

```
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$query = $this->db->get('table_name');
```

or like

```
$param = array('id' => $id);
$this->db->where($param);
$query = $this->db->get('table_name');
```

Comment: The Op could also use $this->db->where($param); even though $param is a bad choice for a variable name in this case.

Comment: maybe it means like this $param = ['siswa.nis' => $id]; $this->db-where($param); this is just my opinion.

Comment: but you can very well: `$param = array('id' => $id); $this->db->where($param);`see [associative array method](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)